# Meaning of "постельного белья"?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I am still at the train. What is included into this phrase:
"предоставление ***постельного белья***".

Does it include sheet, pillow holder et. cetera or is it only the bed sheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical set used in trains now includes 2 bed sheets, a pillow holder, a quilt cover, and 2 towels. These you receive from the conductor, all packed in one plastic bag, and a mattress, a pillow, and a quilt are stored in every compartment on shelves high under the ceiling.

Comment: I believe there is also a comb and a peace of soap. Sometimes there might also be a pair of cloth slippers

Comment: Thank you. This is something that is very interesting and valuable information that is good to know in advance.

Comment: @Alissa - Have you seen the comb, the soap and the slippers yourself? In Russia? What class of trains?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm not sure what kind of train exactly, it might have been Saint-Petersburg - Moscow (or vice versa), or something like Saint-Petersburg - Chelyabinsk and it wasn't a roomette. There were no combs in 2006, but they appeared in 2010ish.

Comment: @YellowSky: I haven't been travelling by train for some time, but they did have that all in Moscow - Murmansk, Moscow - St. Petersburg and Moscow - Vladikavkaz back in the late 2000's. Those were just plain class II sleepers (*купе*), nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when Russians talk about linen (`постельное бельё`) it includes sheet, pillow-case and blanket cover. Since you're in the train you should also get a blanket.

Comment: Well, woolen blankets are there all the time, so they are not part of set being provided by the conductor.